# MYSQL's Timestampdiff not working with PHP's if/else bigger than >

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

The following Mysql SELECT-part of **Timestampdiff**

```
$result_all = mysql_query("SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,aktualisiert,NOW()) AS quote_diff FROM sms WHERE gesendet ='1' AND DATE_FORMAT( aktualisiert,  '%Y' ) = '2015' AND trash ='0' ORDER BY aktualisiert DESC");
```

seems not to work with the **if else** PHP Code

```
<?php
$qd = $row['quote_diff'];
$qdint = intval($qd);
$zahl = intval(100);

echo $qdint;

if ( $qdint > $zahl) {echo " minutes"; }
else { echo " minute"; }

var_dump($qdint); //int(91)
var_dump($zahl); //int(100)
?>
```

Also **var_dump** says, there are both integer.

But why is there no reaction of **is bigger than >** (or is smaller than < or is equal to ==)?

Comment: So script echoes `minutes` instead of `minute` or what?

Comment: 91 is not bigger than 100, so it won't go into the `if` branch. You should get "91 minute". As soon as the value from the database is larger than 100 (for instance 240) you get "240 minutes". I can't really tell what would be the logic behind this...

Comment: @u_mulder
Yes, exactly. If I see any reaction on "is bigger than", then the integer 1 should output "minute" and all the other integers should output minutes.

Comment: @GolezTrol
There are many outputs, out of my database. Some bigger and some smaller than 100. But the output is just "minute". Why?

Comment: You sure? The example you gave is 91, and I wouldn't know why a larger value wouldn't result in "minutes". Nevertheless, the logic seems flawed. It seems to me that `$qdint > $zahl` should be `$qdint != 1`.

Comment: Unfortunately it's also not working, but good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution, without Timestampdiff:

```
$result_all = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sms WHERE gesendet ='1' AND DATE_FORMAT( aktualisiert,  '%Y' ) = '2015' AND trash ='0' ORDER BY aktualisiert DESC");
```

(because a known problem [dev.mysql.com...12.7...user comment from April 9 2004](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

```
<?php  $now = time();
       $lastLogin = strtotime($row['aktualisiert']);
       $diff = $now - $lastLogin;
       $now = date('YmdHis',$now);

       $diffecho = idate('i',$diff);

       if($diff > 59 && $diff < 119) { // 3600 seconds is 1 hour
       echo $diffecho." minute ago"; }
       else { echo $diffecho." minutes ago"; }
?>
```

Use the PHP function **i**date, if you don't want a leading zero.

There is also another cool way on developphp.com:
[Convert MySQL Timestamp to Ago Time Format OOP Tutorial](https://www.developphp.com/video/PHP/Convert-MySQL-Timestamp-to-Ago-Time-Format-OOP-Tutorial)

Maybe I use this later.

Thanks